# django problem with foreign key to user model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a simple userprofile class in django such that

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, choices=UserGender.USER_GENDER,db_column='usr_gender')
    education = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, choices=UserEducation.USER_EDU,db_column='usr_education')
    mail_preference = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=1, choices=UserMailPreference.USER_MAIL_PREF,db_column='usr_mail_preference')
    birthyear = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0,db_column='usr_birthyear')
    createdate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updatedate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    deletedate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=False,null=True, related_name='%(class)s_user_update')
    deleteBy = models.ForeignKey(User,unique=False,null=True, related_name='%(class)s_user_delete')
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField()
```

You can see that `deletedBy` and `updatedBy` are foreign key fields to user class. If I don't write `related_name='%(class)s_user_update'` it gives me error (I don't know why).
Although this works without any error, it doesn't push the user id's of `deletedBy` and `updatedBy` fields although I assign proper user to them.

Could give me any idea and explain the `related_name='%(class)s_user_update'` part ?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name Post your error instead of just saying you got an error. That will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'%(class)s_user_update'` implies that it is a string awaiting formatting. You would normally see it in the context:

```
'%(foo)s other' % {'foo': 'BARGH'}
```

Which would become:

```
'BARGH other'
```

You can read more about python string formatting in the python docs. [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

I can't see how the code you have would ever work: perhaps you want:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # other attributes here
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, related_name='profile_user_update')
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True, related_name='profile_user_deleted')
    # other attributes here
```

If it does work, it is because django is doing some fancy magic behind the scenes, and replacing `'%(class)s'` by the class name of the current class.

Notes on the above:

- The consistent use of *snake_case* for attributes. If you must use *camelCase*, then be consistent for all variables. Especially don't mix *snake_case*, *camelCase* and *runwordstogethersoyoucanttellwhereonestartsandtheotherends*.
- Where you have two attributes that reference the same Foreign Key, you must tell the ORM which one is which for the reverse relation. It will default to 'profile_set' in this case for both, which will give you the validation error.
- Use 'auth.User' instead of importing User into the `models.py` file. It is one less import you'll need to worry about, especially if you don't use the `User` class anywhere in your `models.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about the related_name stuff here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward